# Joomla unable to update in localhost

Tags: joomla, localhost

I'm working with Joomla 3 on localhost

but when i change something in administrator nothing changes in site.

tried changing menu,edititing article even disabling modules .nothing works.

template:JA-NEX

what do you guys think?

Comment: Are you sure the configuration.php database settings are pointing to the database on your localhost and not a live version of your site online? Silly question, but I have made this mistake before.

Answer (score 1):

I used this to setup Joomla 3 as local host and it worked fine.

http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-mar-2013/item/1110-free-e-book-%E2%80%93-introducing-joomla-30-made-easy

hope it helps. sorry but dont have reputation to add comments, so had to be answer.